# How to get one object from array of objects based on id in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have data like this:

```
{
    "global": {
        "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
            "weekDay": ["wednesday"]
        }
    },
    "userEmail": "test1@gmail.com",
    "environments": [
        {
            "userPreference": {
                "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
                    "weekDay": ["friday"]
                }
            },
            "envId": "u1"
        },
        {
            "userPreference": {
                "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
                    "weekDay": ["tuesday"],
                }
            },
            "envId": "u2"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to get `userPreference` object from `environments` array based on `envId`.

Tried this but its returning complete array but I need to return object inside the array i.e. `userPreference`

```
const envData = await preferencesModel.findOne({ userEmail, "environments.envId": envId }, { 'environments.$.envId': envId }).lean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use positional operator. But be ware to use [postional operator in projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

```
db.collection.find({
  "environments.envId": "u2"
},
{
  "environments.userPreference.$": 1
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DjGNJAuotcs)**

Update 1,

The output is As you expected

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      environments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$environments",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.envId",
              "u1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userPreference: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$environments.userPreference",
              0
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hv89sgfSFRg)**

Comment: `await preferencesModel.findOne({ userEmail, "environments.envId": envId }, { "environments.userPreference.$": 1 })` it still returns the array

Comment: u need the `summaryNotificationSchedule`?

Comment: yes but I need to return only object:
`{
"userPreference": {
  "summaryNotificationSchedule": {
 "weekDay": ["tuesday"]
  }
}`

Comment: Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

give the following a go:

find query:

```java
db.collection.findOne(
    {
        userEmail: "test1@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        environments: {
            $elemMatch: {
                envId: "u1"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

aggregation pipeline:

```java
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userEmail: "test1@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            environments: {
                $first: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$environments",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.envId", "u1"] }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: "$environments.userPreference"
    }
])
```